# Manage data (object, key) in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I want to save some object in form of collection (object,key) in objective C. I found `NSMutableDictionary` is the fit to that, but the problem is that I cannot get back the object I want (last added object, first added object ...). Is there a better way of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

For a Key-Value pair, an NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary is the correct solution.

There will only be one value for any given key, and setting a new value will overwrite the old one.

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[myDictionary setValue:@"World" forKey:@"Hello"];
NSLog(@"Hello %@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"Hello"]); // prints Hello World
[myDictionary setValue:@"StackOverflow" forKey:@"Hello"];
NSLog(@"Hello %@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"Hello"]); // prints Hello StackOverflow
[myDictionary setValue:nil forKey:@"Hello"];
NSLog(@"Hello %@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"Hello"]); // prints Hello (null)
```

Comment: So that I need to remember the object of my last key in order to get the last object back, is there another way out?

Comment: You need to remember the key only. I suppose a better example would be the keys "username" and "website" representing "wjlafrance" and "stackoverflow.com". As @Analog File pointed out, if you want an ordered list of values, you should check out NSArray / NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

You can get back your object by using this object's key you added to Dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:@"A" forKey:@"a"];

NSString *strA = [dict objectForKey:@"a"];
```

Put your keys to an NSMutableArray will help you get last/first key.

Hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are for accessing data when you have a key. They are not ordered containers.

If you need to retrieve data based on when you added it to a container you need a LIFO (aka stack), FIFO (aka queue) or deque (aka double-ended queue) kind of container. You can read about them on wikipedia for a starter, but I suggest you read at least one decent algorithm and data structures book, if you want to become a programmer.

AFAIK there are no predefined classes that implement those abstractions in cocoa, but they are all easy to do with arrays. `NSArray` has `lastObject` and `objectAtIndex:` methods, and `NSMutableArray` also have `addObject:`, `insertObject:atIndex:`, `removeLastObject` and `removeObjectAtIndex:` methods that basically are the primitives for LIFO/FIFO/deque access (assuming you use 0 when an index is required by those methods).

Answer (score 0):

NSMutablearray is best approach if you want to get last added object , or object by index . 
object  added  first is at object index 0 and object added last in at [count-1] index